# Are there Windows registry entries to control specific Chrome features?

Tags: google-chrome, script, windows-registry

I need to prevent Google Chrome from offering to save payment information in Chrome 77.0.3865.75 using Windows registry entries that can be deployed via GPO.

The customer is running a web-based payment system and the option to remember credit card numbers and customer names violates the company PCI compliance rules.

I've done some research and the only info I could find refers to Chrome flags. I would rather not use flags in case they are changed or removed in future Chrome updates. The payment stations have different users logging in throughout the day and the users move between stations regularly. I'm interested in a supportable way to implement these changes using a GPO or a script; it needs to be automatic and transparent to the user.

In the flags page, the setting "**Credit card auto-fill ablation experiment.**" can be disabled/enabled, but I'd like to find a way to do this with registry edits instead of Chrome flags. Is this possible?

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 0):

From [Chromium Administrators Policy List](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3) there is an "AutofillCreditCardEnable" option:

> #### AutofillCreditCardEnabled
>
> Enable AutoFill for credit cards
>
> Data type:
>         Boolean [Windows:REG_DWORD]
> Windows registry location for Windows clients:
>         `Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\AutofillCreditCardEnabled`
> Windows registry location for Google Chrome OS clients:
>         `Software\Policies\Google\ChromeOS\AutofillCreditCardEnabled`
> Mac/Linux preference name:
>         AutofillCreditCardEnabled
> Android restriction name:
>         AutofillCreditCardEnabled
> Supported on:
>
> - Google Chrome (Linux, Mac, Windows) since version 63
> - Google Chrome OS (Google Chrome OS) since version 63
> - Google Chrome (Android) since version 63
>
> Supported features:
>         Can Be Recommended: Yes, Dynamic Policy Refresh: Yes, Per Profile: Yes
>
> Description:
>
> Enables Google Chrome's AutoFill feature and allows users to auto complete credit card information in web forms using previously stored information.
>
> If this setting is disabled, Autofill will never suggest, or fill credit card information, nor will it save additional credit card information that the user might submit while browsing the web.
>
> If this setting is enabled or has no value, the user will be able to control Autofill for credit cards in the UI.
>
> Example value:
>         0x00000000 (Windows), false (Linux), false (Android),  (Mac)

Comment: An alernative to using a policy that might change in the future, you can try and use incognito mode, to see if the payment information is not stored.

Comment: While I admit that these things can change and that incognito mode may be a very good solution as it side steps the issues entirely and *forces* separation or wiping of user data when the browser is closed.  In this case the user specifically asked for registry settings.  That is what I provided and I'd be surprised if they change that often and even if they do, the documentation is there. Your position would make a good alternative answer @Ramhound

Comment: Thanks so much for your assistance. I've added the registry entries to one of our pay stations and we're testing it out now. I'll post the results here.